# Publicly accessible balcony with doors to private apartments

Tags: word-request

In Swedish, there's something called *loft*. It's a sort of balcony that anyone can access and from there enter their apartments (looking like [this](https://pumpan1.se/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/cropped-IMG-reduced-e1499434992453.jpg)) as opposed to an windowless staircase inside the building body.

According to the translator, the English word is also *loft*, which make sense. However, where I checked a thesaurus, I saw that it's [a room on an upper floor](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/loft), corresponding to [this](https://as1.ftcdn.net/v2/jpg/01/83/36/76/1000_F_183367641_X23j3PtJxct6IXBtARvnIu4zafJ4OmMl.jpg), rather than the Swedish concept.

Is *loft* an appropriate name for in both languages or does English has something sounding more naturally?

Comment: The English word is not 'loft'. A thing that runs along each floor of an apartment block ('block of flats' in the UK) and allows people to access the apartments is called a 'balcony'. A loft in English is an upper room, usually a room or space directly under the roof of a house or other building, used for accommodation or storage. Also can be an apartment in the upper part of a building, especially a building such as a warehouse or factory that has been converted for people to live in.

Comment: No. The English word loft is only a space under the roof of a house. It's certainly not something which allows access to other houses/flats. English *loft* is obviously a cognate to the Swedish word but it's a false friend in the sense that you are describing. I'd call these "adjoining balconies".

Comment: I would call the structure in your second picture a [mezzanine](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mezzanine), not a loft.

Comment: Similar question on ELU: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/532779/whats-the-word-for-an-outdoor-hallway  "Walkway" was suggested, but "External corridor" or "outdoor hallway" or "open hallway" seems clearest.  I don't think "mezzanine" is right (that is an internal structure).  I've also found "external gallery", in an architectural context from australia

Comment: @BillyKerr I'd like to make a distinction to your suggestion of *adjoining balconies*. While technically correct, a balcony sounds like a ***private** outdoor place*, like a deck, except not at the ground level. And, in my case, the **private** balcony on the other side of the building in the first picture (which actually **is** my building) does adjoin to my neighbor's. So I'd like to have a term for the **publicly** accessible adjoining balcony.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey What would be a natural way of making the distinction between a balcony being a part of the flat and only accessible to the inhabitants and a balcony that's public? It's corresponding to the *hotel vs motel* kind where one accesses the rooms from inside versus outside. I know how to describe it but *don't read very good* is beaten my *illiterate*.   :)

Comment: @JamesK Oh, every hair on my back shivers at that. NB. I mean in to way to object to your comment's correctness. I've been reprimanded by a teacher that both *corridor* and *hallway* must be enclosed, in-doors areas and that stuck in my brain. I gladly take those terms, though - they're self-explanatory. Thanks.

Comment: @KateBunting According to google's image results on *loft*, you're wrong, hehe. Joking aside, isn't *mezzanine* supposed to be something above a certain floor but not quite the next floor? Like of the stairs go halfway up and have a small platform, turn 90 or 180 degrees and continue the other half. If that platform gets big enough to be considered a useful area, that is. Then again, if we consider that the platform is part-way up not halfway up then you're spot on right...

Comment: A mezzanine is an intermediate floor between two storeys of a building, not extending over the whole area. The platform half-way up a flight of stairs is a _landing_.  A loft is an attic (_vind_ in Swedish, I believe).

Comment: (Later) It seems your image can be called a 'loft' in American usage - Oxford Languages says _US. Part of a room on a higher level than the rest of the room._

Comment: @KonradViltersten - I'm sure that would work, possibly even just "public access balcony"

Comment: [External] public  / communal access walkway. A bit of a mouthful, but the best we have in English. As many have said, it's definitely not a loft, and IMHO a corridor is internal to a building and a balcony is either a private open space or an elevated seating area in a theatre or concert hall. In olden days the open access might have been called a cloister, but that was almost always only at ground level. Interesting question, what do they call a similar structure on the inside of a building around, say, an atrium?

Comment: The "loft" pictured in your *corresponding to [this](https://as1.ftcdn.net/v2/jpg/01/83/36/76/1000_F_183367641_X23j3PtJxct6IXBtARvnIu4zafJ4OmMl.jpg)* link qualifies for that designation because *it's a "room" above the ceiling* somewhere within the "normal" living space of a house ("atriums" like that are fairly uncommon in Anglophone dwellings, so we don't really have common words for them).

Comment: "to the translator" humanoid or AI?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Neither... Or, maybe, I'm not sure how to classify it. It's a webpage (tyda.se) where you type a term and get a bunch of suggestions and examples for a word. It's not *human* but certainly not *AI*. Just an electronic dictionary. How would you place it: human or AI?

Comment: It's a machine. the translator is 100% not human. Maybe you should try Google translator or DeepL or write a description of the architecture feature in English and see what turns up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there may be a technical term used by architects (I've seen "[circulation space](https://firewize.com.au/definition/circulation-space)" and a comment mentions "deck access") there seems to be a lexical gap.

Walkway seems a possible term, or "balcony walkway" to clarify:

> The action of the play takes place in Jamie and his mother’s flat and on the
> balcony walkway in front of the flat. ([source](http://nectar.northampton.ac.uk/12503/1/Contemporary_Gay_Drama_The_End_of_a_Modernist_Crusade_Bathurst_L_2005_10296981_web.pdf))

> Residents must keep all walkways, stairwells, communal balconies and other shared spaces free from personal items.

> Looking along a balcony walkway in a block of flats on the Parkhill estate. ([source](https://historicengland.org.uk/images-books/photos/item/EFC01/01/05/015/51040))

However the meaning is also clearly expressed by terms like  "External corridor", "outdoor hallway", "open hallway" or "external gallery".

Comment: I suspect that, as the comments suggest, the construction isn't widely popular in English speaking areas, so there's no specific, natural term for it. It's said that Inuit have 50 names for snow, while we don't. For the same reason. (Well, we do have a few but it's like 10 maximum.)

Comment: It's not so uncommon, but it is seen as undesirable and unfriendly.  The 50 names for snow is a myth.  But if snow means "meteorological ice" you might be surprised at how many English words there are: snow hail blizzard flurry frost hoar rime needle-ice graupel sleet freezing-rain glaze avalanche powder slush hard-pack corn champagne drift chowder CRUD CHOP    That's 22 already.

Comment: If it helps, properties built in this manner are described as having "deck access", at least in the UK (though in my experience it would not be idiomatic to refer to the outside walkway as a deck). I learned this term from the housing market - it's a feature which is very common in social housing stock/council housing estates, so mortgage lenders commonly refuse to lend on properties with deck access, as a way to avoid lending on ex-council-housing properties without specifically banning them.